# Underbrace overlapping text

Tags: equations, amsmath, brackets

I am trying to type the equation in the figure below. The text on the brace is long and it does not wrap around. Can you help me to solve the problem? Thanks.

Equation: [image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{underoverlap}
  \begin{document}

  $Q_{t+1}(s_t,a_t)= \UOLunderbrace{Q_{t}(s_t,a_t)}_{old\ value}  + 
  \UOLunderbrace{\alpha_{t}(s_t,a_t)}_{learning\ rate}
  \bigg(
      \UOLoverbrace{
         \UOLunderbrace{R_{t+1}}_{reward}+
         \UOLunderbrace{\gamma}_{discount\ factor}
         \UOLunderbrace{max Q_{t}(s_t,a)}_{optimal\ future\ value}
      }^{learned\ value}-
      \UOLunderbrace{Q_{t}(s_t,a_t)}_{old\ value}
  \bigg)$
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you write completely MWE please? (starting with `\documentclass`)

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to use `underoverlap`, that won't leave the necessary space; you could use `\substack`, but in this case I'd prefer doing it “by hand”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xsub}[1]{%
  \mbox{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

$Q_{t+1}(s_t,a_t)= \underbrace{Q_{t}(s_t,a_t)}_{\xsub{old value}}  +
  \underbrace{\alpha_{t}(s_t,a_t)}_{\xsub{learning rate}}
  \bigg(
      \overbrace{
         \underbrace{R_{t+1}}_{\xsub{reward}}+
         \underbrace{\gamma}_{\xsub{discount\\factor}}
         \underbrace{\max Q_{t}(s_t,a)}_{\xsub{optimal\\future value}}
      }^{\xsub{learned value}}-
      \underbrace{Q_{t}(s_t,a_t)}_{\xsub{old value}}
  \bigg)$

\end{document}
```

[image]